# UI frozen when updating pie-chart control

Tags: c#, charts, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm using the chart controls from `WinRTXAMLToolkit`, to draw a pie chart. The chart is updated on the screen using the values from a few `slider` controls.

When the sliders values are changed, I call in a function to calculate a formula (say compound interest) based on the sliders' values.

And then I change the `ItemsSource` of the chart's `SeriesDefinitions` to point to the new collection of data.

I'm trying to have a 'live' PieChart which updates instantly. The problem is when I keep changing the values of the sliders, there is a 1-2 second delay for the chart to draw itself again - and this makes the slider movement 'freeze' in between for a second.

Is there any way around this problem ? Can I move the chart-updation to a different thread so that the UI thread remains free and doesn't freeze up ?

Comment: How many datapoints are there?

Comment: The PieChart has two sections. There is also a separate chart for a `StackedColumnSeries` in the same `UserControl` which can have 5-10 datapoints depending on user input. Both charts are updated from a `Slider`'s `ValueChanged` event.

Comment: Have you tried running using a profiler? It doesn't make sense that there would be the delay you describe given how few points you mentioned.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I searched around but it looks like the Visual Studio profiler is not available for WinRT apps.

Comment: Here is a description of the profiling options: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/12/performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try update it using another thread and run it async.

One way is to insert it into Update fuction, and do:

```
await Update()
```

While Update and the method which it called in are async.

Comment: This is the line that updates the pie chart : `((PieSeries)this.MyChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = PieList;` and calling it from a `Task` or a different thread raises exceptions.

Comment: You can't update a UI control on a background `Task`, so I am not clear what you're suggesting @AniruddhaVarma.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem may be that you're changing the ItemsSource. This is a more intensive operation because a lot of things happen in the background. Could you use an ObservableCollection and update it instead of replacing it?

Comment: I did that but ran into a COMException as described here : [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730124/winrtxamltoolkit-charting-comexception-when-use-of-inotifypropertychanged)